# How to build a Loki server Docker image using Docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, grafana-loki

I have created a directory and mounted all the required files in each directory but when I try to create the docker image, It creates Promtail and Grafana but the LOKI wouldn't create. I get the error message below;

ERROR: for 9c35c983e8e4_cbxs_loki_1  Cannot start service loki: Mounts denied:
You can configure shared paths from Docker -> Preferences... -> Resources -> File Sharing.

I have mounted the files just as the order containers..
Please help

docker-compose.yml

Please see the file on the link below
https://docs.technotim.live/posts/grafana-loki/

```
version: "3"
networks:
  loki:
services:
  loki:
    image: grafana/loki:2.4.0
    ports:
      - "3100:3100"
    restart: unless-stopped
    command: -config.file=/etc/loki/loki-config.yml
    networks:
      - loki
  promtail:
    image: grafana/promtail:2.4.0
    volumes:
      - /var/log:/var/log
      - /Users/emma.egbu/CBCS/Promtail:/etc/promtail
    ports:
      - "1514:1514"
    restart: unless-stopped
    command: -config.file=/etc/promtail/promtail-config.yml
    networks:
      - loki
  grafana:
    image: grafana/grafana:latest
    user: "1000"
    volumes:
    - /Users/emma.egbu/CBCS/Grafana:/var/lib/grafana
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - loki
```

Thank you so much ! That was helpful...
For anyone going through the same struggle, here was what I did:
I went to edit the docker daemon config file
sudo nano /etc/docker/daemon.json - Probably you won't have write access so
`sudo vi chmod 666  /etc/docker/daemon.json` - This will allow u write
I pasted the file below

```
{
    "log-driver": "loki",
    "log-opts": {
        "loki-url": "http://localhost:3100/loki/api/v1/push",
        "loki-batch-size": "400"
    }
```

Afterwards I restarted my docker then also
`docker-compose up -d --force-recreate` - to run up the docker-compose file

Comment: could you share the dockerfile/docker-compose.yml?

Comment: Please see the file on the link below
https://docs.technotim.live/posts/grafana-loki/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined a volume mount for `/var/log` in your container, but most likely don't have this defined in Docker Desktop (under Docker -> Preferences... -> Resources -> File Sharing). You are probably best off removing this volume definition from the compose file, unless you actually want to read these logs on your Mac.